# Declare and initialise variables in Python as necessary

Tags: python, variables

I entered in a competition where I was given an input file. The problem was that there is a party organised and the host's guest are invited depending upon how much the host likes the guest. The value is +ve if the guest is a good friend or -ve if the guest is not a good friend. The higher total of the liking value of guests, the better it is.

So, the first line of the input file is how many test scenarios are there. The next line consists of how many guests are there. And the next line consists of the number of liking values for each guest in that test scenario.

For eg

```
2

8
1 -4 5 -2 -1 8 0 1

3
-1 -2 -4
```

Here, we have 2 test scenarios. In the first test scenario, there are 8 guests. The 8 guests have the individual values of 1 for the first guest, -4 for the second guest and so on.

Same for the second test case. The first, second and third guests have the liking value of -1, -2 and -4 respectively.

I know what to do if these values are given to my Python program as an input. But I can't find a way to extract these values from a text file and store them in individual variables.

Comment: Storing this values in individuals variables is the wrong approach here. Use a data structure such a dictionary to map these specific values to specific keys. A list could also be used, but a dictionary works best when the data you have has specific labels.

Comment: Thanks for the dictionary suggestion @ChristianDean. Although, I think that a 2D list of only the 'guest liking values' will be better as I also `len` instead of storing the number of guests as the key.

Comment: Also, I noticed I do not need to mention the number of guests explicitly in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you don't.  There's no point in dynamically assigning variables, because there's no way for you to write code that knows about those variables.  It's easier to read them into a list instead:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    num_test_cases = int(next(f))
    for _ in range(num_test_cases):
        next(f)  # blank line
        num_guests = int(next(f))
        guest_values = [int(val) for val in next(f).split()]  # Reading values in the list
        result = your_code(num_guests, guest_values)
```